# SSIS packages getting locked out in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, package, sql-server-data-tools

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2017 (SSDT) to work on SSIS packages.

Whenever I close Visual Studio, I have to reload packages again and that causes it to lock.

What should I do to keep my SSIS packages in VS so my work is saved without getting lost or locked?

Every-time I open VS, I have to reload the same package I worked, and it locks me out.

Comment: Hi ! Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question is really hard to understand :/ You should try to make it more explicit, maybe add images or quotes, that will make it more readable. The better it is, the more users will help you !

Comment: Why does reloading your packages cause your VS to lock?  I would have your PC-operations person take a look at that and fix it.